# Почему текст выходит за пределы сетки?

Tags: css, css3, html5, css-grid

Почему размер сетки не изменяется в зависимости от размера шрифта, поскольку в настоящее время текст, который находится в элементе `header` и `footer`, находится вне их?
Я добавляю `font-size:25;`.

мне нужно поместить все элементы в `div` для этого?

```css
:root {
  --light: #666666;
  --dark: #000000;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav article article" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: 60em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
  background-image: url(code.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header,
footer,
article,
nav,
div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: var(--light);
  opacity: 0.85;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
}

#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}


/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */

@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "article" "nav" "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
  <h1>header</h1>
</header>

<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<footer id="pageFooter">
  <p>MADE BY</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: @Antonio112009, почему ответ удалил?

Comment: Alexandr_TT, что бы не возникало таких вопросов, мои первые строчки в `css` начинаются так `*{margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}
  html, body{width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: #2b2b2b;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ой)
Проблема крылась всё таки в `h1`, а не в padding'е.
Ибо h1, изначально, имеет свой размер шрифта и отступ.

Решение:
Добавить вот такие правила для h1

```
#pageHeader h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --light: #666666;
  --dark: #000000;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav article article" "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: 60em;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;
  background-image: url(code.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header,
footer,
article,
nav,
div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: var(--light);
  opacity: 0.85;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
/* Вот решение */
#pageHeader h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
}
/* ----------- */

#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
}

#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}


/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */

@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas: "header" "article" "nav" "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
  <h1>header</h1>
</header>

<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<footer id="pageFooter">
  <p>MADE BY</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: а как же [это](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2tsw2owgvx5omm/2018-12-08_054130.png) ?

Comment: @UbuntuUser, у `p` тоже есть margin, а вот шрифт придётся уменьшить.

Answer (score 2):

Причина в  использовании фиксированного значения для `header` и `footer` , поэтому  есть переполнение  `grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px`. Нужно заменить фиксированные значения функцией [minmax ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax), чтобы высота регулировалась, если содержимое больше.

```css
:root {
 --light: #666666;
 --dark: #000000;
}

body { 
 display: grid;
 grid-template-areas: 
   "header header header"
   "nav article article"
   "footer footer footer";
 grid-template-rows: minmax(80px,max-content) 1fr minmax(70px,max-content);  
 grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
 grid-row-gap: 10px;
 grid-column-gap: 10px;
 height: 60em;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;

 background-image: url(code.jpeg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}



header, footer, article, nav, div {
 padding: 1.2em;
 background: var(--light);
 opacity: 0.85;
 color:black;
 border-radius: 1.2em;
}

#pageHeader {
 grid-area: header;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 24px;
}

#pageFooter {
 grid-area: footer;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

#mainArticle { 
 grid-area: article;      
}

#mainNav { 
 grid-area: nav; 
}
  /* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
 body { 
   grid-template-areas: 
  "header"
  "article"
  "nav"
  "footer";
   grid-template-rows: minmax(80px,max-content) 1fr minmax(70px,max-content) 1fr minmax(70px,max-content);  
   grid-template-columns: 1fr;
   }
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">
  <h1>header</h1>
</header>

<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<footer id="pageFooter">
  <p>MADE BY</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Такой вариант я тоже рассматривал)